# Why is DEFAULT_NUM_DIRECT_ARENA derived from PlatformDependent.maxDirectMemory()?

Tags: java, netty

Hopefully I've got all the messy details right here, it's a bit subtle.

By default Netty will usually set `io.netty.maxDirectMemory=MaxDirectMemorySize` and enable "no cleaner" buffers if possible. If "no cleaner" buffers are in use, Netty's direct memory & Java's "native" direct memory are tracked independently -- because Netty needs to do its own accounting to track memory allocated by `Unsafe.allocateMemory` in "no cleaner" buffers.

This means that the theoretical maximum memory set aside for off-heap data in a Netty service running default config is often roughly `io.netty.maxDirectMemory+MaxDirectMemorySize` -- or `2 x MaxDirectMemorySize` by default. This is kind of quietly documented over here:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/6cebb6069b3f30eedaddb12d2d22a6dd66277047/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/PlatformDependent.java#L132-L139

So that's fine, even if it is a bit surprising.

But things seem to get a little weird when you try to explicitly set io.netty.maxDirectMemory and MaxDirectSize to different values. For example, we were trying to clamp down our theoretical memory ceiling a little to play nice with cgroups: the service in question was getting OOM killed, so we got a little aggressive and, once we realized the relationship between MDMS/i.n.mdm, set MaxDirectMemorySize and io.netty.maxDirectMemory explicitly to minimize our ceiling -- `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1g` and set `-Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory=3221225472` with "no cleaner" direct buffers enabled.

I expected this effectively be a no-op change as far as Netty was concerned since we had `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3g` before we explicitly set `io.netty.maxDirectMemory`. However, we observed drastically less in-use direct memory reported. Suspecting it probably had something to do with the reduced MaxDirectMemory size I eventually found this, which I think could explain the difference.

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/6cebb6069b3f30eedaddb12d2d22a6dd66277047/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocator.java#L92-L97

Why use `PlatformDependent.maxDirectMemory()` here (which will be set to the value of `MaxDirectMemorySize` rather than the inferred `io.netty.maxDirectMemory`) instead of e.g. `DIRECT_MEMORY_LIMIT` (which *is* set to the explicit or inferred value of `io.netty.maxDirectMemory`)?

It's possible I've misunderstood something along the way and I'm not necessarily complaining, just trying to understand: is this intended behavior? An oversight/bug? Something that is difficult to change because folks now rely on the existing semantics? Something else?

Comment: great question (with all the nitty-gritty details) for someone who is a new contributor!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a bug.... Thanks for bringing it to my attention, proposed fix:

https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/8452